# "paddingLeft" disapears when I use setText() + setBackgroundDrawable() on a Button

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles

I have this Button :

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btStatSerie"
        style="@style/ButtonPopUp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="@string/start_serie" />
```

Which call this style

```
<style name="ButtonPopUp" parent="ParentTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bt_menu_principal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:drawableRight">@drawable/ic_flche_blanche_bas</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

I set the text using `setText()` and at the same time `setBackgroundDrawable()`  to express the change clearly to the user.

This remove the paddingLeft the style is providing.

Any ideas to solve this issue except writing a line under every setBackground() to set a padding from the code ?

And most important to me, WHY is this happening ?

ty

Edit : xml drawable :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_border_pressed"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_border_focused"
      android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_border" />
```

where bt_border and Cie.  looks like with only color modifications :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke 
    android:width="2dp" 
    android:color="@color/blue" /> 
<solid android:color="@color/blue" />    
<padding        
   android:bottom="5dp"       
   android:left="5dp"        
   android:right="5dp"
   android:top="5dp" />     
<corners android:radius="7dp" /> 
</shape>
```

The new background I set (using setBackgroundResource() now)  is also following the above modele (no selector). The padding is there when the screen is displayed for teh first time so really it is linked somehow to changing the background. Also, this issue was there before I start using a selector as xml drawable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies within the fact that the default Button drawable contains paddings by default. The new drawable your setting probably does not have this padding and therefor padding disappears.

For example the default button drawable for ICS consists of a set of nine-patch images. Those nine-patch images contain padding.

Posting some source code of the drawable you're using could help!

Comment: I do use dp for my padding ?? Do you mean I should use SP ?

Answer (score 1):

You must set paddings after calling setBackgroundDrawable() method.
You can make a class extends Button, and override the setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable drawable) method, like this:

```
@Override
public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    int l = getPaddingLeft();
    int t = getPaddingTop();
    int r = getPaddingRight();
    int b = getPaddingBottom();

    super.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    setPadding(l, t, r, b);
}
```

Then replace your Button tag with this custom class

Comment: I tried the order issue with no success. I don't see how creating a custom class would further help me.  **btSerie.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_menu_principal);      btSerie.setPadding(15, 0, 0, 0);       btSerie.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.vitesse_start_serie));**

Comment: @Poutrathor in your layout xml file, replace <Button with your custom Button class. Then when you call btSerie.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_menu_principal), the overrided method will set paddings automatically, so you don't need to call btSerie.setPadding(15,0,0,0);

Comment: My point is that using a custom class just to encapsulate a setPadding is overkill. After all, adding set padding everywhere I need it or changing all my layout is roughly the same amount of work. But more important, I already called them in this order and it does not work !

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you.